# Communication between API and Interface using axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I have I have a problem to etablish a communication between the API and the Interface
To be more clear : I send a JSON file from the API , but I can't recover it and display it in the Interface , The JSON is verry simple : {"name":"joe"}

Here is my code : in API : (`http://localhost:8080/route1`)

```
const jsontest=require('../models/test'); 
.
.
router.post('/', (req,res)=>{
       res.send(jsontest);  
        });
module.exports=router;
```

and in the interface side (`http://localhost:8081/`)

```
<template>
.
.
  <v-btn x-large color="grey"  class="d-flex align-start flex-column mb-6" @click="getData" 
 >Start</v-btn>


      <div v-if="todos">
        <li>{{todos}}</li>
      </div>
</template>
```

followed by :

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios';
const WorkersURL='http://localhost:8080/route1';

export default {
 data(){
   return{
     drawer: false,
      todos:''
   }
 },  

 methods: {
 getData:function()
 {
    axios.post(WorkersURL)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data) ;
      this.todos= response.data.name;    
          })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors = e
    });

  }
},
 mounted(){
     this.getData
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `res.json()` in your server:

```
router.post('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.send(jsontest);  
});
```

and remove `{}` in `axios.post(WorkersURL,{})`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work (the same problem)... when I inspect the code of the interface I get this error :  POST http://localhost:8080/route1   net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Same thing I tried it without {}, it seems that it's the same problem

Comment: is your server up?

Comment: Yes I use visual studio to run the interface server, and  cmd to API

Comment: In console every thing is OK, in the interface nothing is displayed , so I do Inspect code of the page and I see this in red : POST localhost:8080/route1 net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: I think your request doesn't send to your server, you can simply add `console.log('com')` in `router.post(...)` to check if your request arrive at server or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211168/discussion-between-joe-and-behappy).